# Login page not redirect to target location in PHP?

Tags: php

Hi everyone please help i have developed my first website www.ncrwallpaper.com its under testing.
My problem is that whenever i login on from login page.
1st its not redirect to target page
2nd its already logged in but in current page its not showing..

here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbfunctions.php');
include_once('top.php');

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $a=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $b=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $c=$mysqli->query("select * from users where email='$a' and pass='$b'");
    $count=$c->num_rows;

    if($count==1){
        $f=$c->fetch_object();

        //value assign in session_id
        $_SESSION["id"]=$f->id;
        $_SESSION["email"]=$f->email;
        $_SESSION["name"]=$f->name;
        $_SESSION["contact"]=$f->contact;

        if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) $url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
            else $url = "index.php";

        header("Location: $url"); 
    } else echo "Please enter valid email id and password";
}

?>
```

this code is already working on localhost

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" id="input-email" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="input-password" class="form-control" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" name="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Rocky its css in top.php

Comment: redirecting with `header()` wont work if header is already sent, make sure youre not echoing somthing before you call `header()` even whitespaces between `?> <?php` harm your code

Comment: editing this post made it harder since `?> <?php` is problem here -_-

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `header` after you output something which will be the css in the `top.php` you have 3 options you use  [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137604/4244993) , [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137771/4244993) or a meta refresh to redirect

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=' . $url . '">';
```

the `0` is the delay how long the site should be shown till it refreshes

Comment: Nice, learned something new :) Did not know there was an alternative. +1

Comment: @sguetsch you're welcome (:

Comment: 3rd option - use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-notes) (see second note)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ob_start()` & `ob_end_clean()`

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include('dbfunctions.php');
include_once('top.php');

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $a=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $b=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $c=$mysqli->query("select * from users where email='$a' and pass='$b'");
    $count=$c->num_rows;

    if($count==1){
        $f=$c->fetch_object();

        //value assign in session_id
        $_SESSION["id"]=$f->id;
        $_SESSION["email"]=$f->email;
        $_SESSION["name"]=$f->name;
        $_SESSION["contact"]=$f->contact;

        if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) $url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
            else $url = "index.php";

        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        header("Location: $url"); 
    } else echo "Please enter valid email id and password";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in place of your header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.assign('your desired location');
</script>
```

Note:close php before script tag and open php after closing script tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbfunctions.php');
?>
<?php include_once('top.php'); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$a=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$b=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$c=$mysqli->query("select * from users where email='$a' and pass='$b'");
$count=$c->num_rows;
if($count==1){
$f=$c->fetch_object();
//value assign in session_id
$_SESSION["id"]=$f->id;
$_SESSION["email"]=$f->email;
$_SESSION["name"]=$f->name;
$_SESSION["contact"]=$f->contact;
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
$url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
else 
$url = "index.php";

echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\">
window.location.assign('blaahh.php');
</script> ";
}
else{
echo "Please enter valid email id and password";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: you cannot echo <script>

Comment: You will have to use `echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">`

Comment: Nice reply all of you dear its working with java script..but why not we can use header('location:test.php');

Comment: @PrabhasMandal, If javascript is disabled, then it wont work!!!

Comment: [Code only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/246338)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some JS. Just put this code in your header:

```
 ?> // close php
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.assign('location');
</script>
<?php // open php again
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP:**

```
header("Location: yourpage.php");
exit;
```

You have to use exit or die after header in order to stop execution of your code. Also, the code has to be executed before any output.